# Sent e-mails into mbox with getmail

Tags: email, imap, mbox

I'm using `getmail` to fetch my e-mail inbox into an `mbox` file (with `IMAP`). It works great, but the process got only *Inbox* folder's content.

Is there a way to include sent e-mails too? Official documentation do not mention that.

Tx.

Answer (score 0):

In the `retriever` section add a `mailboxes` section. The [getmail configuration guide](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/configuration.html#retriever-parameters) gives this example:

```
mailboxes = ("INBOX", "INBOX.spam",
"mailing-lists.model-railroading")
```

You might have to play around to find out whether your sent mail folder is called

- `Sent`
- `"Sent Mail"`
- `INBOX.Sent`
- ...

It depends on the configuration of your mailserver. Configuring Thunderbird as a one off should show you your folder names if you can't find another way of doing it.